# Firebase initialize sdk with service account from cloud storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to initialize our sdk following the instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

Basically, I created a service account and stored the accompanying json for that service account in cloud storage. Great. Now the example says I should reference that Json by:

> Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the
> file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key

But, we aren't storing the file local to these cloud functions, we are storing it in cloud storage. How do we specify a path to a non-local file?

Answer (score 1):

The Admin SDK does not support remote configurations.  It needs to be local, either on disk or in memory.  You will have to write code to download the config from the storage bucket somehow, then feed that to the SDK.

Comment: Alright, that's pretty strange. Cloud functions are serverless, so it's pretty weird to design something that wants to check the local filesystem. It would be very inefficient to download a file every time the function runs. Do you have any reference code which we could use to see how this is 'normally' done?

Comment: You normally deploy the credentials in a file along with the function source code (as you see in some official samples) so it can be accessed locally.  Or you can use [environment config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to provide them.  Both options are extremely common.

Comment: I am not aware of any official samples which exemplify what you're describing. The example I linked assumes the file is already present locally. Can you please link to these examples? Alternatively, if we provided the json object in an env var, what Env var is the sdk expecting? I assume not GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS since the documentation specifies that is expecting a path

Comment: Exemplified in official samples: [1](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth) [2](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase) [3](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/line-auth) [4](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/spotify-auth) [5](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/okta-auth).  I got tired grepping after 5, but you can find more.  Or you can always use the default service account for the project if you want.  But this gets you the one you want.

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is an env variable for the path to the credentials file.

Comment: @Juancki However, you can't sent process environment variables when deploying with the Firebase CLI.  The closest similar options is environment config that I linked to in my second comment here.

Comment: Your first comment mentions Cloud Functions. If by that you're referring to Google Cloud Functions (or any other GCP-managed runtime), then you don't need a service account json file at all. That's only needed when running locally or on non-GCP infrastructure.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Well, I was getting this error on the backend: `"severity":"ERROR","message":"FirebaseAuthError: Failed to determine service account. Make sure to initialize the SDK with a service account credential.`

So I started looking into how to initialize with a service account.

Comment: If you want to use the default service account for your project as Hiranya mentioned, you can initialize the Admin SDK with no parameters.  But if you need a specific account, it has to be locally available by some means.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize the Admin SDK locally (not deployed) you need to download the service account json file and make it accessible by:

1. Setting an env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set to the path "/home/user/serviceaccount.json".
2. Include the service account file in the functions file and access it via relative path [programmatically](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/561d73b0357f4b03f4952242ee9513d57708f068/instagram-auth/functions/index.js#L24).

Once deployed the there is a runtime service account `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and the environment variables are already set.